# page not updating with database

Tags: admin, database, admin-menu

I have code which updates the database fine, but the page doesn't update correctly! I have to refresh the page a second time for it to update correctly.

Here is the code below (`funcitons/admin-website-options`). The most important line is the `<input type="radio" ....` line:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_website_menu');

function add_website_menu()
{
        add_menu_page( 'website Options', 'website Options', 'administrator', 'website_options', 'echo_website_menu');
}

function echo_website_menu()
{
        if(isset($_POST['submit-change-front-story']) )
        {   
                $new_post_id = intval($_POST['front']);
                global $post;
                $args = array('tag' => 'front-page');
                $posts = get_posts($args);
                function get_ids($post) {
                        return $post->ID;
                }   
                $posts = array_map("get_ids", $posts);
                untag_posts($posts,'front-page');
                wp_add_post_tags($new_post_id, 'front-page');
        }   
        ?>  
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Manage Stories</h2>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUIEST_URI']?>" method="POST" class="story-admin-form">

                <br/>
                <h3>Front Page Stories</h3>
                <?php query_posts('cat=5'); // all posts with category of "story" ?>
                <div class="posts">
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) :
                                global $post;
                                $post = array();
                                the_post(); ?>
                                <input type="radio" name="front" value="<? echo the_id(); ?>" <? echo has_tag('front-page', get_the_id()) ? "checked":"" ?>/> <? echo the_title(); ?><br/>
                        <?php endwhile;?>
                        <br/>
                        <input name="submit-change-front-story" type="submit" id="submit-front-page-story" value="Change Front Page Story" />
                </div>
             </form>
         </div>
         <?php
}
?>
```

Every time I change the front-page story, both of the select options are "checked", but I can view the posts in the admin view and only one of them has the 'front-page' story. (???) And when I refresh the page, then the options have only one selected.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using a tag, you could use `get_post_meta()` to retrieve a custom field? Set a meta field like `featured` and test to see if it's set to one or something.

```
$featured = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'featured', true);
if ($featured === 'yes') echo 'selected';
```

I hope I understood your question the right way and that this helps you out.